# Why does Android 4 with Phonegap ignore css sizes in em?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using em's instead of px to set sizes of HTML containers and images in my Phonegap app.

**Example:**

```
<div id="outer">
 <div id="inner">
  Hello
 </div>
</div>

<style>
#outer{font-size:0.5px}
#inner{font-size:2em;width:2em}
</style>
```

Using the style above, #inner should have a width of 1px and font should also have 1px size.

This works well on:

- All Android Browsers
- iPhone (Browser and native Phonegap build)
- Native Android 2.x app with Phonegap

**BUT**

it doesn't work for a native Android 4.x app with Phonegap (tested on Emulator and real devices).

For some reasons font-size in #inner seems to be correctly reduced to 1px **BUT** the container itself ignores the parent font-size.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the issue.

Android 4 rounds up font size values less than 8 up to 8.

So, if you use `font-size:0.5px` it'll change the font size to 8px.

Comment: I have same issue, what is your solution?

Comment: @onurtaskin From what I can tell there is no solution. I simply increased the base font size in my design template to a minimum of 8px.