# PhoneGap Android different font size with web site

Tags: android, css, cordova

I wrapped my web site with phonegap. But all fonts are bigger than usual. If I open my page with browser from my phone, the fonts are normal. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: How are you setting your font sizes in your css? Post some code.

Comment: I found the same issue there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861176/why-does-android-4-with-phonegap-ignore-css-sizes-in-em